# Dynamic Inheritance in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, dynamic

Does such thing as dynamic inheritance exist in Java?

Just to clarify, by dynamic inheritance I mean: can I specify from what class I inherit certain class at runtime? (A inherits from { X | X ∈ {P, T, Q} })

I am just trying to understand what are my options if I need to implement, say, class Animal, which will have the following child classes: FlyingAnimal, WalkingAnimal, SwimmingAnimal, etc.

At the same time, I need to subdivide Animal into Humans and NonHumans, which will have slightly different behaviors. What I want to do is to derive Humans and NonHumans from Animal, and then derive Animal from Walkable, etc. - I want to decide which one it would be at the runtime (assuming that an animal can either walk, or fly).

Comment: Short answer: no.  Long answer: noooooo.  You cannot do this dynamically at runtime.

Comment: @LouisWasserman ha ha, good one :-)

Comment: You should implement all the classes you need.  And select one at the runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*from what class I inherit certain class at runtime*

No. Java is a compiled language with compile time type checking. However, it is *possible* to use a byte-code manipulation library like [BCEL](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/) to create bytecodes at runtime; per the BCEL homepage one *interesting application is the creation of classes from scratch at run-time*

Comment: Thanks @Elliot! I'll take a look at it, although, I don't feel that my Java knowledge is sufficient to get into byte manipulation (at least, yet). But is there a way to inherit class X from one class (A), and then do something like casting of the result to the instance of a child class (B)?

Answer (score 3):

The proper way or solving such situations usually is (de-) *composition* and *delegation* (these are the keywords to search for).

For example, your class could *contain* an object of these classes, and simply use it instead of inheriting.

i.e.

```
interface Engine {}
class Diesel implements Engine {}
class Electric implements Engine {}
class Car /* NOT extends Diesel/Electric */ {
  Enigne engine; /* delegate or composition pattern */
}
```